# what is the correct way of using pm2 programatically

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am trying to use `pm2` in my class programatically but i aint getting any response or errors from the ***API***.

Here is my code: process.js

```
    "use strict";
const pm2  = require('pm2')
const util = require('util')

class process {
  /**
  * Class constructor function
  * @Class Process
  * @method constructor
  * @return {undefined}
  */
  constructor () {}

  /**
  * Gets the list of running processes being managed by pm2
  * @Class Process
  * @method list async  
  * @return success {object} || fail {object}
  */
  async list () {  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pm2.list((err, res) => {
        if(err){reject(err)} resolve(res)
      })
    })
  }
}

module.exports = new process
```

And here is how i'm trying to access it:

```
  // @method init [koa middleware] async
  async init (ctx, next) {   
    try{
      const ls = await proc.list(); console.log(ls) 
      ctx.body = ls
      //next()
    }   
    catch(e){
      ctx.throw(401, 'error', { error: 'random error' })
    }
  }
```

For some reason, i am not getting any response or error in the console. What might be the issue?

Comment: Why `new` in the export statement?

Comment: i'd rather export a new object by default than add another line of code after i require the class